# multi thread issue

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, invoke

I'm using a timer to reset a lable I use as a warning box. Basically, if the user does something (more specifically, something goes wrong, ex : He uses a word not recognized by the program), this catches what went wrong early and returns to him what happened so he can change the input.

The reset blanks out the label after 5 seconds to prevent him from seeing something like "please do not use chinese characters" and maybe still thinking an old error is still up. This is what I got reading the invoke (since I hear begininvoke requires an endinvoke, I chose invoke).

```
private void lblWrn_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timee = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    Timee.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerClearWrn);
    Timee.Enabled = true;
}

string empty = "";
private void timerClearWrn(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
{
    lblWrn.Invoke(new Action<Label>(lblWrn), new object[] { lblWrn, "" });
}
```

I am not too sure where I am going wrong with this, and looking up examples, cannot figure out which part to change. Can someone explain to me the error or invoke a bit more?

Comment: Could you provide the error message you are seeing?

Comment: "since I hear begininvoke requires an endinvoke, I chose invoke" EndInvoke is not needed, only if you want to wait till it is executed.

Comment: I would also add that the EndInvoke allows you to obtain the result of the operation.  If you do not need it, it is also possible to use the BeginInvoke without the EndInvoke method call.

Comment: If you use a Windows.Timer you don't have threads and don't need Invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Windows Forms application, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer, then you don't need Invoke, as the timer callback is executed on the main thread.

Also, don't create a new timer on every text change.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `Control.BeginInvoke` ***does not*** need an `EndInvoke`; it is `Delegate.BeginInvoke` that *does*.

First, I would also recommend using a `Windows.Forms.Timer`, since it looks like you are using winforms - that will automatically fire on the UI thread, making all the problems go away - just run *the code you want to run* in the handler (don't use `Invoke` etc)

The *problem* in your example is that the parameters don't match; an `Action<>` expects a method name (more accurately: a *method group*) to be invoked, and the parameters in the array must be suitable. Since you don't show the method you plan to invoke, I can't help there - but `lblWarn` isn't a method (it is a field).

Comment: +1 because all the salient points are there, but I think you could improve the wording some.  Pretty sure .NET has no such thing as a "pointer to the method", you can use the name of a *method group* and a *delegate* encapsulates a function pointer (along with the target object), perhaps you meant one of those.  In the case where a delegate is accepted, passing in a field is not a-priori an error, if it has delegate type.

Comment: @Ben thanks, "method group" is indeed a better term (although equally confusing to readers, perhaps) ;p Re the field - *as the parameter to a delegate constructor* I can't think of a way that would ever work.

Answer (score 1):

on this line
lblWrn.Invoke(new Action(**lblWrn**), new object[] { lblWrn, "" });

shouldn't the bold part be a function and not a object?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Option 1 is a little clunky. Options 2 and 3 are better.

**Option 1:** Continue with general strategy of using `Control.Invoke` but use code that calls `Invoke` correctly, disable auto resetting of the timer, and removes the event handler.

```
private void lblWrn_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Timee = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    Timee.Elapsed += this.timerClearWrn;
    Timee.AutoReset = false; // Raise the Elapsed event only once
    Timee.Enabled = true;
}

private void timerClearWrn(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
{
    lblWrn.Invoke(
      (MethodInvoker)(()=>
      {
        lblWrn.Text = "";
      }), null);
    var Timee = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    Timee.Elapsed -= this.timerClearWrn;
}
```

**Option 2:** Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`.

**Option 3:** Use the `SynchronizingObject` property of `System.Timers.Timer`. This is my preferred option when timers are to be created and used dynamically from a UI thread.

```
private void lblWrn_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Timee = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    Timee.Elapsed += this.timerClearWrn;
    Timee.AutoReset = false; // Raise the Elapsed event only once
    Timee.SynchronizingObject = this; // Tell the Timer to raise the Elapsed event on the UI thread
    Timee.Enabled = true;
}

private void timerClearWrn(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsed)
{
    lblWrn.Text = "";
    var Timee = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    Timee.Elapsed -= this.timerClearWrn;
}
```