# Systems.timer.timer unwanted multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I recently switched my code from using the windows.forms.timer to the systems.timer.timer and it has resulted in a multithreading error. I'm using the timer to trigger just one event so multithreading shouldn't be an issue. To give more detail I have implemented the timer at follows:
At the top of the class I have:

```
Private Shared timr1sec As System.Timers.Timer
```

When the program loads (Private Sub Test_load):

```
timr1sec = New System.Timers.Timer(1000)
AddHandler timr1sec.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
```

In OnTimedEvent I call several subroutines, and write some data to the screen using a ListView object. VisualExpress throws the multithreading error on the last line of this code, which is in OnTimedEvent

```
    Dim itm As New ListViewItem(str(0))

    itm.SubItems.Add(str(1))
    itm.SubItems.Add(str(2))
    itm.SubItems.Add(str(3))
    itm.SubItems.Add(str(4))
    itm.SubItems.Add(str(5))

    ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {itm})
```

Any idea what it is about this new timer that's causing VisualExpress to say I'm multithreading?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191903/which-net-timer-to-use

Comment: possible duplicate of [multi thread issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610429/multi-thread-issue)

Answer (score 3):

`System.Timers.Timer` raises its `Elapsed` event on a threadpool thread.

You should use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which always uses the UI thread.

If you really want to, you could set the `SynchronizingObject` property on the `Timers.Timer` to tell it to marshal its events to the UI thread, but there's no point.

Comment: I was using System.Windows.Forms.Timer but I'm using the timer as a stopwatch and as I've found out Windows.Forms.Timer is not designed for this. A nice explanation is here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: I've found a few examples of synchronizingObject but I'm not sure how this applies. Could you tell me more or point me to a good example?

Comment: `Timers.Timer` can call `SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke` to run the callback in the UI thread

Comment: OK, I've set timr1sec.SynchronizingObject = textbox1 and that synchronized the timer thread with the form. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that by setting SynchronizingObject, you will lose precision, since you need to wait for the message loop before your handler runs.